# Spring RESTful backend and Angularjs front end : How to add parameters from the client side?

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest

I have a spring restful backend, one of the mapping is this:

```
    @RequestMapping("/getPeopleList")
    public List<Person> getPeeps(@RequestParam(value="ssid", required=true) Integer ssid){
    return Backend.getPeople(ssid);
   }
```

How do i make a request to this api?  I am doing this with my angularjs

```
   $http.get(url+'/getPeopleList').success(function(peeps) {

        console.log(peeps);
    });
```

but this doesnt work......
I also tried this

```
     $http.get(url+'/getPeopleList/234').success(function(peeps) {

        console.log(peeps);
    });
```

The id 234 is a random id but that doesn;'t work either. I get 404 or 400 bad request everytime .

Comment: what error you are getting in console ?

Comment: @swapnesh "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)"  This is for the first http request

Comment: can you check that the url is forming correctly and headers are properly set ?

Comment: @swapnesh url was wrong lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are asking for `@RequestParam` but you are passing `@PathVariable`. 
Please see their [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).
Just change to :

```
 $http.get(url+'/getPeopleList?ssid=234').success(function(peeps) {
        console.log(peeps);
    });
```